# Python. Некорректно работает if, когда добавляю input

Tags: python

Всем привет!

Есть две функции, одна тянет данные из другой.

Логика простая: в первую функцию ввожу данные в input, вторая уточняет, действительно ли я это хотел ввести

```
 def first_layer(x,y):

    if answer == 1:
        return x
    if answer == 2:
        return y
    else:
        return 'Вводи только 1 или 2'

x = 'Один'
y = 'Два' 

answer = int(input('1 - Один, 2 - Два: '))
result = first_layer(x,y)

print (result)

def second_layer(o,p):


    if first_layer(x,y) == x:
        return o
    if first_layer(x,y) == y:
        return p
    else:
        return 'Дружище, вводи только 1 или 2'
    
o = f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {x}?'
p = f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {y}?'

result = second_layer(o,p)
print (result)
```

И все работает отлично. В первой функции ввожу 1, мне возвращается, что я выбрал 1. Ввожу 2, возвращается, что выбрал 2

Но только стоит мне во второй функции добавить input

```
o = int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {x}?'))
p = int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {y}?'))
```

Так if сразу начинает ошибаться и если я в первой функции выбираю "2", во второй функции получаю ответ, предназначенный для "1"

например:

```
1 - Один, 2 - Два: 2
Два
Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал Один?
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что делаю не так.
Если можно, очень подробно. Опыт в программировании 1 месяц.

Спасибо!

Comment: если хочешь понять используй дебагер

Comment: Вторая функция это какая? Первая функция это какая? Приведи полный код и опиши, что получается, а что должно быть.

Comment: PyCharm - дебагер хороший.

Comment: @Эникейщик это и так полный код. Первая функция  def first_layer (x,y) возвращает "Один" при вводе 1 и "Два" при вводе 2. Вторая функция def second_layer (o,p) возвращает "Правильно я понял, что ты выбрал один?" если первая функция вернула один и "Правильно я понял, что ты выбрал два", если первая функция вернула два

Comment: Где же полный код, если прямо в вопросе написано "только стоит мне во второй функции добавить"?

Comment: у @Эникейщик высокие требования к точности и структурированности написания запросов, а запрос действительно написан неточно. Например, его сбивает фраза " стоит мне во второй функции добавить", которая с кодом вообще не бьётся (я понял причину минут через 15 - см. мой ответ).  Полагаю, мой ответ должен был полностью ответить на вопрос (тогда просьба принять его - галочка слева под треугольником), если нет - задайте мне доп. вопросы. И обязательно учитесь структурированно подходить к написанию кода.

Comment: @Эникейщик, у автора код действительно полный, тут он прав. Но совершенно перепутанный + запрос неверно написан и не соответствует коду (возможно, автор сам не заметил, что он в main часть действий выполняет, а не во "второй функции"). См. мой ответ, если интересно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К работе if это не имеет никакого отношения. Переменная о стоит в основной последовательности, а не во второй функции, как написано автором вопроса, поэтому её строка выполняется сразу после print, нет никакого if.

К "что делаю не так" - не только сама ошибка "не так" - неверен сам стиль написания кода, нельзя так писать, так как очень тяжело читать, а стиль сам потенциально порождает ошибки (что и случилось). Например, вторая функция second_layer почему-то "сидит" посреди основной программы, постоянные параметры х и y зачем-то передаются в первую функцию first_layer (аналогично o и p - во вторую), а единственная изменяющаяся переменная answer просто берется за счет области видимости. Зато вторая фунцкция до х и у добирается тоже через область видимости. И т.д. Крайне рекомендую продумать, что вообще хочется иметь, и структурированно написать всё заново.

Фактически код основной части (в "нерабочем" варианте автора с новыми o и p) сейчас выглядит так:

```
x = 'Один'
y = 'Два' 
answer = int(input('1 - Один, 2 - Два: '))
result = first_layer(x,y)
print (result)
#следующая строка выведет "1" всегда, так как она стоит к исполнению без всякого условия
o = int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {x}?'))
p = int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {y}?'))
result = second_layer(o,p)
print (result)
```

Вот так можно переписать, чтобы убрать ошибку:
(def second_layer перенесён наверх, а в переменной result теперь запоминаем, какие данные бот выдавал ранее, не надо снова вызывать first_layer из second_layer - и надёжнее, и быстрее так)

```
def first_layer(x,у): #оставил аргументы только с учётом, что х и у   однажды будут в других версиях динамически меняться

    if answer == 1:
        return x
    elif answer == 2: #elif правильнее, чем просто if тут 
        return y
    else:
        return 'Вводи только 1 или 2'

def second_layer(result): #передаём сюда результат первой функции

    if result == x:
        outcome = int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {x}?'))        
    elif result == y:  #elif правильнее, чем просто if тут
        outcome= int(input(f'Я правильно понял, что ты выбрал {y}?'))
    if outcome!=1 and outcome!=2:
        outcome='Дружище, вводи только 1 или 2'
    return outcome

if __name__=="__main__":

    x = 'Один'
    y = 'Два' 
    answer = int(input('1 - Один, 2 - Два: '))

    result = first_layer(x,y) 
    print (result)

    new_result = second_layer(result)
    print (new_result)
```

Comment: Сергей, спасибо за ответ, но мне все же хотелось бы, чтобы возвращались нужные значения именно посредством двух функций. Первой, принимающей ответ и второй, которая смотрит, какой ответ был в первой и в соответствии с этим выдает уже новый ответ

Comment: Сергей, я постараюсь более полно объяснить, зачем мне это нужно. Я пишу Телеграм бота. Мне нужно, чтобы он был +- "умным" и на основании того, какие данные он получал ранее, выдавал новые ответы. Чтобы можно было строить диалоги по разным сценариям. Вот в коде сверху, например, два сценария: "1" и "2" но уже на второй функции код сбивается и выбирая сценарий №2 он мне дает ответ для сценария №1

Comment: Можно писать что угодно:-) Но нельзя писать так. Например, зачем телеграм-боту иметь определение второй функции посреди main? Все определения функций обычно сверху. Я же написал выше, почему он сбивается. У вас имя "о" является результатом исполняемой функции input (). И эта функция всегда выполняется, она же не зависит от условий. Она выполняется ещё до вызова second layer. Я добавил комментарий в код в ответе.

Comment: Опасна, например, сама идея передачи o и p с вводом значений, как переменных, во вторую функцию. Даже не предскажу, как отработает.

Comment: Сергей, а можете показать, какие манипуляции нужно сделать со второй функцией, чтобы все было ок? Я правда не догоняю :'(

Comment: Сейчас перепишу, как понимаю, что нужно. Я боты никогда не писал, но уверен, что метод такой совместной работы функций уже продуман, и есть в интернете. Лучше велосипед не изобретать бы вам, а разобраться, как делать принято в таких случаях.

Comment: Теперь работает - больше не путает. Код можно подправить по вкусу теперь в тех моментах, которые другими хочется видеть. Принимайте, если ответил:-)

Comment: Сергей, спасибо!